# Search JSON using user date input from dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm looking to be able to take a user date input from three different drop down menus (day, month, year) and use a JSON file that I created by exporting my database to a JSON file to pull back the data that matches the date inputted by the user.

Here's an example of a record in my JSON file:

```
"items": [ 
{"id":"1","artistName":"REDNEX","songTitle":"COTTON EYE JOE"," startDate":"1995-01-14"},
```

If the users input matches a date in the JSON array then I wish to display the artist name and song title. How would I go about doing this? I have never worked with JSON before now.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Watch out for that empty space in `" startDate"`.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume obj as your JSON data.

```
var output = [];
var searchField = "startDate";
var searchVal = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
for (var i=0 ; i < obj.list.length ; i++)
{
    if (obj.list[i][searchField] == searchVal) {
        output.push(obj.list[i]["artistName"] + "," + obj.list[i]["songTitle"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say "JSON", but your post includes what appears to be a raw javascript object. **JSON data is simply a string, which can then converted to an object.**

Addtionally, you want to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select the artists of interest.

```js
var userDate = "1995-01-14";
var itemString = '[{"id":"1","artistName":"REDNEX","songTitle":"COTTON EYE JOE", "startDate":"1995-01-14"}]'
var items = JSON.parse(itemString);
var filtered = items.filter(x => x.startDate === userDate);
for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; ++i)
  console.log(filtered[i].artistName + ": " + filtered[i].songTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter` function

```js
data = {"items": [ 
{"id":"1","artistName":"REDNEX","songTitle":"COTTON EYE JOE","startDate":"1995-01-14"},
]};


function getArtistByDate(date) {
  items = data["items"];
  return items.filter(
      function(items){ return items["startDate"] == date }
  );
}

console.log(getArtistByDate("1995-01-14"));
console.log(getArtistByDate("1995-01-15"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use takeWhile() from Lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#takeWhile. (Moreover, once you get started with Lodash you are going to find a wealth of utility functions that you cannot live without.)

```
var userInputDate;
var matchingItems = _.takeWhile(items, {'startDate': userInputDate});
// matchingItems is an array of all items with the same startDate
```